# VBA Looping & Filtering Issue

Tags: excel, loops

I'm running into an issue with looping through tabs in my workbook. The code I am working on is supposed to perform the following:

- Loop through all worksheets except the ones titled "BOAT" & "Data"
- Select cell "A2" (A2 contains the value to filter)in each worksheet that it is looping through and use it as the autofilter value for the "Data" tab
- Then copy and paste the filtered data into the respective tab that is looping through.

The issue I am running into is my code isn't picking up on the active sheet in the loop. Is there a way to create a variable to for the worksheet currently being looped through?

Code below. Thank you!

```
  Sub updatedata()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsheet2 As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.name <> "BOAT" And ws.name <> "Data" Then

        Call filter1

    End If
    Next ws


End Sub

Sub filter1()

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lastrow2 As Long
Dim wSheet As Worksheet
Dim rInput As String

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set wSheet = ActiveSheet
rInput = wSheet.Range("A2").Value

Sheets("Data").Activate
lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Y" & lastrow).AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:="=*" & rInput & "*"

lastrow2 = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("G1:G" & lastrow2).Copy
wSheet.Activate
Range("A4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Rows(4).EntireRow.Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: you dont activate sheet before calling filter1

Comment: What sheet would I need to activate? The way I'm calling this is through a button on the first tab of my workbook which is the "BOAT" sheet.

Comment: Avoid activating - instead `filter1` should have a `Worksheet` argument. Or combine `updatedata` and `filter1` and reference `ws` within the `For Each` loop.

Comment: yes but there will be others changes to make because : Set wSheet = ActiveSheet, in fact he sould remove all "activate" and copy with destination

Comment: @BigBen would you mind showing me how that would look? Still a novice on the VBA spectrum. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @cutzero would you also mind showing me what you mean? Thank you as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"Is there a way to create a variable to for the worksheet currently being looped through?"*

Yes, using a `Worksheet` variable as an argument in `filter1`. 
Avoid using `Activate` or making `Range` calls without specifying the `Worksheet`.

```
Sub updateData()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "BOAT" And ws.Name <> "Data" Then
            filter1 ws 'no need to use Call
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

By passing `ws` as an Argument to `filter1`, all `Range` calls are fully qualified with the `Worksheet` in question. This is easily accomplished with a `With...End With` block - note the period `.` in front of `.Range("A2").Value`, `.Range("A4")`, etc - equivalent to `myWs.Range("A2").Value`, `myWs.Range("A4")...`, etc.

```
Sub filter1(myWs As Worksheet)
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastRow2 As Long
    Dim rInput As String

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    With myWs
        rInput = .Range("A2").Value

        With .Parent.Sheets("Data")
            lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            .Range("A1:Y" & lastRow).AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:="=*" & rInput & "*"
            lastRow2 = .Range("G" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            .Range("G1:G" & lastRow2).Copy
        End With

        .Range("A4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .Rows(4).EntireRow.Delete
    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I tried running it and it says I'm getting a "compile error:Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment. "

Comment: What line is highlighted?

Comment: Do you have `filter1 ws` or are you missing the `ws` portion?

Comment: I was able to work around that error. It was a typo in my code. But I am now getting a run time error 424 object required and it is highlighted on the following line: rInput = .Range("A2").Value